# исправить баг м прыжком в юнити

Tags: c#, unity3d

он должен прыгать только тогда, когда стоит на земле.
вот код:

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class player : MonoBehaviour {

```
// делаем скорость и встраиваем РБ (физику)
public float speed = 20.0f;
private Rigidbody2D rb;
public Animator charAnimator;
public SpriteRenderer sprite;
bool onGround;
Collider2D other;
// Use this for initialization
private void Awake (){
    // даём физике путь к ригидбади
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();
    charAnimator = GetComponent<Animator> ();
    sprite = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
}

void Start () {
    
}
//движение,переворот
void Move(){         
    //движение
    Vector3 temp = Vector3.right * Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
    transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards (transform.position, 
        transform.position + temp, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    //переворот
    if (temp.x < 0)
        sprite.flipX = true;
    else
        sprite.flipX = false;
}
void Jump(){

    rb.AddForce(Vector2.up * 2000);
}
void CheckGround() {
    if (other.tag == "Platform")
        onGround = true;
    else
        onGround = false;
    

}
// Update is called once per frame
void Update (){ 
    CheckGround ();
    
    if (Input.GetButton ("Horizontal")) {
        Move ();
    }


    if (onGround == true && Input.GetButtonDown ("Jump")){
        Jump ();
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что метод `CheckGround()` находится в `Update()`. Судя по тому, что у вас там используется `Collider2D other`, смею предположить, что это идея была использовать `OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D)` и `OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D)

Решение скорее всего такое:
Убрать `CheckGround()` из `Update()`, добавить

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Platform"))
        onGround = true;
}

void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Platform"))
        onGround = false;
}
```

так же обратите внимание, что это метод для триггеров, так что если вы используете физику, то тело на нем стоять не будет. Вам скорее нужны методы ниже, а также убрать галку trigger с коллайдера земли/платформы

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Platform"))
        onGround = true;
}

void OnCollisionExit2D(Collision2D other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Platform"))
        onGround = false;
}
```

и удалите глобальную переменную `Collider2D other` она вам отдельно не нужна.